# Linux Mint 20.3 really slow boot in (loader)

Tags: boot

I previously have booted Mint 18.x on my high end desktop from a USB SSD and it loads in around 15 seconds..

I recently got a new SSD and installed Mint 20.3 on it. The problem is with this new install, the screen gets stuck at my motherboard logo for a couple minutes before finally going to the next Linux Mint screen. I've tried reinstalling this several times with different partition setups, and slight variations but the problem persists. Here are some out puts from terminal diagnostic:

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 12.560s (firmware) + 3min 44.839s (loader) + 3.480s (kernel) + 1.010s (userspace) = 4min 1.891s 
graphical.target reached after 1.005s in userspace
```

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
342ms networkd-dispatcher.service                          
293ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
283ms dev-sdb1.device                                      
171ms upower.service                                       
164ms accounts-daemon.service     
etc....
```

```
$ sudo df -Th 
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      ext4      865G  8.8G  812G   2% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb2      vfat       94M  5.2M   89M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   44K  1.6G   1% /run/user/29999
```

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=002adaac-5e2d-4b43-ada9-0321daa624ae /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=DBC4-8EFB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile
```

```
$ blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p2: LABEL="nvme" UUID="BA2C31472C310045" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8263f52b-ab79-4a82-aca6-abbe304a5fbe"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="EA18E9DB18E9A6B3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="33e33b53-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="0E46215F46214933" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="33e33b53-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="5672621C7262015B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="33e33b53-03"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="002adaac-5e2d-4b43-ada9-0321daa624ae" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e8c7415a-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="DBC4-8EFB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e8c7415a-02"
```

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: everything points to your linux still booting in < 15s, but your system firmware taking roughly eternity to find your bootloader. That can have many reasons, including it taking forever to initialize the SSD. Can you check in your UEFI setup whether you're trying to boot from something else (e.g. network, any devices that act like a USB drive) before you try booting from your NVMe?

Comment: I forgot to say... This LM 20.3 installation is on a USB 3.2 SSD... I also tried moving it to the highest boot order in UEFI and it is still dead slow.. Maybe I should try cloning my old USB SSD onto the new one and see if that OS will boot normally on the new hardware, that would be good enough.